# Converting OCaml to F#: How to convert type for OCaml Format module

Tags: types, f#, ocaml, external

I am converting the OCaml [Format module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) to F#; see my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397737/converting-ocaml-open-box-and-close-box-to-f).

To get started I changed

> type size
>
> external size_of_int : int -> size = "%identity"
>
> external int_of_size : size -> int = "%identity"

to

> let size_of_int = sizeof`<int`>

and a few other adjustments which I know is not correct, but it allowed me to convert all code related to open_box and close_box expect these three lines.

Now I have to just change these three lines so that I can test the subset of the format module that I did convert.

I know that the lines with size_of_int and int_of_size while external will probably rely on some function in the F# core. I also know that [%identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482624/ocaml-identity-function) can probably be ignored for the conversion.

My best guess is that I only need to create a simple type named size with size_of_int and int_of_size, but how?

EDIT

Based on answer by [Jeffrey Scofield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821679/jeffrey-scofield) I was able to create the following F# code.

```
type size =
  interface
    abstract size_of_int : int -> size
    abstract int_of_size : size -> int
  end

type size = int
let size_of_int i = i
let int_of_size s = s
```

which allowed my subset of the Format module to successfully compile.

EDIT

[Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197411/jack-p), who answered below, has a version at [FSharpx.Compatibility.OCaml.Format.Format.fs](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Compatibility) 
I havent' tested it, but it is the most compelete version I have found at present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines:

```
type size
external size_of_int : int -> size = "%identity"
external int_of_size : size -> int = "%identity"
```

Create an abstract type that is identical to int.  The conversion functions
are no-ops (the identity function).  I don't know the F# idioms, but in
OCaml you can use an interface file and avoid the cleverness with "%identity".

```
(* Interface file *)
type size
val size_of_int : int -> size
val int_of_size : size -> int

(* Implementation file *)
type size = int

let size_of_int i = i
let int_of_size s = s
```

Hopefully this translates more readily into F#.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, there's another, more type-safe way you can handle this code in F#: by using unit-of-measure type annotations.

When you write `type size = int` in F#, `size` is simply an alias for `int` -- so the F# compiler will happily allow you to mix and match them. For example:

```
let someSize : size = 10
let badSum = someSize + 3  // 'someSize' is used like another other 'int'
```

If you wanted a bit more type safety, you could define a unit-of-measure type `Size` and use it like this:

```
[<Measure>] type Size
type size = int<Size>

let inline size_of_int i =
    LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<Size> i
let inline int_of_size s = int s

// Now, using a variable of type 'size' where an 'int' is expected
// (or vice versa) will result in a compilation error.
let someSize = size_of_int 10
let badSum = someSize + 3  // compilation error here
```

If you're coming over to F# from OCaml, this may be somewhat familiar. Unit-of-measure types in F# are erased at compile-time, but they help reduce simple math mistakes in code -- phantom types can be used in OCaml for the same purpose.